# Prove that set is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, recursion

Show that the set N* of finite sequences of nonnegative integers is countable.

Where do I start? I think I have to prove that there is a bijection between N* and N (set of natural numbers), but how do I get there?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the function that sends a sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)$ to $2^{a_1} 3^{a_2} 5^{a_3}\ldots p_n^{a_n}$, where $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime number.

Comment: Okay, but are those sets finite? They seem infinite, going up to an unspecified term. I just don't have enough of an idea how to do this yet.

Comment: What do you mean? The product of finitely many numbers is surely finite.

Comment: @AdamEisenstein A set of the form $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, or $\{p_1,\ldots p_n\}$ for that matter, where $n$ is a natural number, is finite almost by definition.  To be finite means to have a bijective correspondence with some natural number.